# Twitter Button Always Shows 0. Tried Everything So Far

Tags: twitter

I've spent 3 days of solid work trying to get the tweet button counting tweets, but it won't.

I tried all solutions on dev.twitter.com without result.

http://www.webhostingbreak.com is the place where it's not working.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
data-count="horizontal" data-via="webhostingbreak">Tweet</a>
```

I also have widgets.js called in the header of my template.
Lastly, a curl -I test of any url of my site gives an HTTP 200 OK response.